# How do I store the number of rows affected in a variable using php?

Tags: php

Below is how my code looks like

```
$update = mysql_query("update profile set status=1 where id='$id_ex'")or die("error from $update".mysql_error());

printf("Affected record is : %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Thanks

Comment: `$variable = mysql_affected_rows();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly store in a varaiable

```
$update = mysql_query("update profile set status=1 where id='$id_ex'")or die("error from $update".mysql_error());
$affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();
printf("Affected record is $affected_rows");
```

below is php documentaion
[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)